# Динамично создаваемый ифрейм

Tags: jquery, iframe

Проблема в том, что при создании `iframe` в нем загружается главная страница, а не та, которая была указан в src. А если вручную вставить `iframe`, то все ок.

Код:

```
var target_name = Math.floor(Math.random()*999999),
iframe = '<iframe name="'+target_name+'" id="'+target_name+'" src="/callback.php"></iframe>';
JQ('.iframe-area').append(iframe);
JQ('#form').attr('target', target_name).submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
  $("<iframe name='zazaza' id='azazaza' src='zazaz'></iframe>").appendTo("body");
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SMxpm/1/

Comment: фигня какая то у меня тогда получается... Пробовал указывать любые src - все равно в ифрейме показывает страницу на которой находишься.

Comment: некоторые сайты не фреймятся 'Load denied by X-Frame-Options'.

А так, вот вам демо http://jsfiddle.net/SMxpm/2/